# Integral separation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I have an integral of the form:
$$ \int_Y{\int_X{\mathbb{1}_{(\alpha x +y \geq \gamma)} f(x) f(y) dx dy}}$$
where $\alpha, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it possible to separate the integral in this case?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear! what do you mean by $1_(\alpha x+y)$?

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the typos now. $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ is the indicator function of $A$.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "separate the integral"?

Comment: I mean is it possible to write it as a product of two integral one over $X$ and the other over $Y$. I want to evaluate the integral but I'm finding difficulties to get rid of the indicator function.

Comment: @kagami: Hey OP are you there? :) Take a look at the new answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we want to evaluate the following integral

$$I = \int\!\!\!\int\limits_\Omega  {{\bf{1}}(A)f(x)f(y)dxdy}\tag{1}$$

Where $\Omega$ is the domain of integration in the $xy$ plane and $A$ is another region in that plane. According to the definition of the indicator function we have

$${\bf{1}}(A) = \left\{ \matrix{
  1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left( {x,y} \right) \in A \hfill \cr 
  0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left( {x,y} \right) \notin A \hfill \cr}  \right.\tag{2}$$

Now, combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ you can write

$$I = \int\!\!\!\int\limits_{\Omega  \cap A} {f(x)f(y)dxdy} \tag{3}$$

That's all you can do based on the assumptions mentioned in the question!

Now, **if** the region ${\Omega  \cap A}$ can be written as

$$\Omega  \cap A = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right)|{x_1} < x < {x_2},{y_1} \le y < {y_2}} \right\}\tag{4}$$

then $(3)$ can be simplified as follows

$$\eqalign{
  & I = \int_{{x_1}}^{{x_2}} {\int_{{y_1}}^{{y_2}} {f(x)f(y)dydx} }   \cr 
  & \,\,\, = \int_{{x_1}}^{{x_{}}} {f(x)\left( {\int_{{y_1}}^{{y_2}} {f(y)dy} } \right)dx}   \cr 
  & \,\,\, = \left( {\int_{{y_1}}^{{y_2}} {f(y)dy} } \right)\left( {\int_{{x_1}}^{{x_{}}} {f(x)dx} } \right) \cr}\tag{5}$$

Also **if** $A \subset \Omega $ then you have

$$\eqalign{
  & \Omega  \cap A = A = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right)|\alpha x + y \ge \gamma } \right\}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right)| - \infty  < x <  + \infty ,\gamma  - \alpha x \le y <  + \infty } \right\} \cr}\tag{6}$$

and hence you can write $(3)$ as

$$\eqalign{
  & I = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\int_{\gamma  - \alpha x}^{ + \infty } {f(x)f(y)dydx} }   \cr 
  & \,\,\, = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {f(x)\left( {\int_{\gamma  - \alpha x}^{ + \infty } {f(y)dy} } \right)dx}  \cr} \tag{7}$$

since the limits of integration are not constant in $(7)$ you **cannot** just simplify it to products of one-dimensional integrals like $(5)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you can do :

$$\int_Y\int_X 1_{(\alpha x +y \le \gamma)}f(x)f(y)dxdy=\int_Yf(y)\{ \int_{x \ge \frac{\gamma -y}{\alpha}}f(x)dx \}dy$$

First integrate over $x$ and then over $y$, I don't think you can rewrite this as a product of integrals without other informations on $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You can go one step further in case $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$
are absolutely integrable and vanish as $|x|\rightarrow \infty $ then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}dyf(y)\int_{\frac{\gamma -y}{\alpha }}dxf(x) &=&\left[
yf(y)\int_{\frac{\gamma -y}{\alpha }}dxf(x)\right] _{y=-\infty }^{+\infty
}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}dyyf(y)\partial _{y}\int_{\frac{\gamma -y}{\alpha }}dxf(x)
\\
&=&-\int_{\mathbb{R}}dyyf(y)\frac{1}{\alpha }f(\frac{\gamma -y}{\alpha })\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I cannot understand what you have done? Can you explain it to me regarding to equation (7) in my answer? :) I will be so thankful!

Comment: You are right. There is a term missing, i.e. I made a mistake.